# Excel opens by himself

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have a problem with Excel. When I work on my computer, this problem happens when I take a pause or when I don't work on my computer, or when I work on my computer. Excel opens by itself.

Excel starting a session unexpectedly and therefore unsolicited and displays the message below. This has happened 5 to 6 times since this morning.

This problem occurs since many months and I didn't find a solution.

When Excel opens, it opens a blank spreadsheet and I get this error:

[image: pic]

"Insufficient memory. Microsoft Excel, can no longer open or save documents.

-To increase available memory, close workbooks or programs that you no longer need.

-To free up disk space, delete files that you no longer need. "

Can you help me?

Comment: If you want assistance you will have to provide a translation into English.

Comment: Thanks you it's done ! =)

Comment: I would repair your Office installation.

Comment: Also check for total disk space on your computer as well as background processes using too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go to this folder:

C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel

Delete **all Files and Folders** from this folder, and restart Excel.